Why my website name appearing on Google is the url?
I uploaded a website online made in HTML, CSS and JavaScript (without any framework or library like React, Next...). I figured that when I search for the website on Google, the url is showing as the website name (look image here).
I followed Google rules at this link: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names, I added the following meta tag inside the head section in the HTML file:
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Mini Gingembre">

I also have several h1 tags with "Mini Gingembre" as content but this is not showing as the site name on Google, URL instead.
How can it be possible that Google engine didn't find any way to identify the real site name with all these infos?


When Google lists a page in search results, it shows the name of the site the page comes from. This is called the site name. Note that the site name is different from the per-page title links (title links are specific to each web page, whereas the site name is for the entire site).


Google's generation of site names on the Google Search results page is completely automated and takes into account content from a site's home page and references to it that appear on the web.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names#how-site-names-in-google-search-are-created
You can't make that url field use a string, its googles name url people see instead of a long untidy name.

Thank you for the reply. Is « Mini Gingembre » a long untidy name? It sounds like a basic one to me…

Does your page have a title tag?

I think I misunderstood and thought you we're trying to update the url field with a more human friendly one - I understand now that you mean in the results google is using your url as your title instead of the the title you chose, this is something Google can change depending on the query type, they might edit your site name slighty to be more accurate but if you have a title tag you should be golden after a few crawls.

Yes this is what I want! Yes I also have a title tag in the head section, which content is also « Mini Gingembre », you can have a look at the html file by inspecting my page https://www.minigingembre.com/, but this is weird that I have to crawl it, why isn’t it working on the first try at the publishing?

How long ago did you make these changes? It can take some time to reflect in ser. If your site is new then google is evaluating it every time it visits so it will improve if your content and keywords uses are relavant and not spammy but all seems fine at a glance.

It’s been a month since it got online now. Is it the case for every websites? Like each website name shown is the url at the beginning and becomes a relevant name after some time? It is not possible to have a relevant site name immediately?

That should be long enough, I have seen it happen before but it is not a policy, in my case the page quality was just low, I made some title and keyword changes and it recrawled after resubmitting to search console.  They will chose what they see best unless there is a problem. Try checking w3 validator and something like sem rush to give you some more insights into how the crawlers view your content. Also some incoming links using your desired title wouldn't hurt either.
